# Historical Bitcoin full node counts

Tags: nodes

Is there an online record of historical Bitcoin node counts? If so:

- When did the record keeping begin?
- Are IP addresses available?
- Did Satoshi and most early adopters run Bitcoin nodes over Tor or were their real IP addresses revealed to other Bitcoin nodes?

Answer (score 8):

1. Everyone that ran a node has/had the ability to record lists of other Bitcoin nodes and their IP address with a "getaddr" request (assuming they allowed incoming connections). I am not aware of a centralized online database of these records dating back more than 1 year: https://bitnodes.21.co/dashboard/?days=365
2. Yes: https://bitnodes.21.co/nodes/
3. Some early adopters used real IP addresses and others (including Satoshi) obscured their IPs with Tor, VPNs, or other means.